# Memory leak in ImageDataGenerator.flow()

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have big dataset that do not fit in memory so, I have broken it into parts. I am training by loading one part at a time and then applying Image augmentation using ImageDataGenerator. This keeps increasing the RAM uses every epoch and eventually memory gets filled and kernel dies.

My generator code:

```
 def data_gen(N,bs):
    #N=Number of pieces in which traning set is divided
    #bs=batch_size
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=180,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    vertical_flip=True,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    zoom_range=0.2
    )
    while True:
        print('Memory Status:')
        printm()#It prints memory status
        for n in range(N):
            X,y=load_traning_data(n+1)# It loads one piece of traning data n+1 is file number.
            datagen.fit(X)
            batches=-1
            for X_mini,y_mini in datagen.flow(X,y):
                batches=batches+1
                if batches >= len(X) / bs:
                    break
                yield X_mini,y_mini
```

If I don't use ImageDataGenerator like this:

```
def data_gen(N,bs):
    #N=Number of pieces in which traning set is divided
    #bs=batch_size
    while True:
        print('Memory Status:')
        printm()#It prints memory status
        for n in range(N):
            X,y=load_traning_data(n+1)
            for X_mini,y_mini in mini_batch(X,y): #mini_batch() generates mini_batches of X and y. 
                yield X_mini,y_mini
```

It works fine.

Also if I only load one piece of training data and apply image augmentaion it works fine. So, problem seems to be on fitting ImageDataGenerator on multiple traning pieces.

Model is fitted with fit_generator:

```
gen=data_gen(16,32) #16 peices of traning data and batch_size=32
model.fit_generator(gen,steps_per_epoch=8000/32,epochs=30)
```

I am using Googlecolab.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because ImageDataGenerator. flow() will load all of the data into memory, regardless of the batch_size parameter. You have to feed data into flow() in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `import gc`

Add `gc.collect()` after `datagen.flow(X,y)`.

Which means each time after you call `datagen.flow(X,y)`, collect the garbge.